# Inductor not working

Tags: circuit-design, inductor

I tried building a toroidal inductor with the following parameters:

OD= 1.400 in / 35.55 mm +/- 0.75 mm

ID = 0.900 in / 23.0 mm +/- 0.55 mm

Ht = 0.500 in / 12.7 mm +/- 0.50 mm

Wire: solid insulated copper 14G

Data sheet for the material: https://www.fair-rite.com/43-material-data-sheet/

[image]

For some reason inductor the is not working when a connect it to a battery (doesn't work as a magnet). I was expecting to get more than 100 micro Henry out of it.

Is it possible that is not working because the wire is insulated with thick plastic? What are other possible reasons for it not working?
Thank you!

Comment: How did you measure the inductance? Looks ok so far. Link to toroid data sheet?

Comment: how does one measure inductance with a battery?

Comment: Maybe your measurement technique is not correct. Can you please edit your question to add detail about how you measured the inductance? If it was not over 100uH, how many uH was it?

Comment: @Rodion Degtyar, may I introduce the "Cool Magnet Man"? I learnt much magnet stuff from this crazy magnet guy: (1) The Cool Magnet Man
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=234552&p=1437668&hilit=the+magnet+man#p1437668.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it doesn't work as a magnet so I figured it doesn't have any inductance. Here's a link to the material datasheet: https://www.fair-rite.com/43-material-data-sheet/

Comment: And you might like to skim my penzu inductance lab log for some references on how to measure inductance: https://penzu.com/p/362a4d17. Happy learning. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, your coil thing is NOT a electromagnet. You may try to buy a cheapy real electromagnet: like shown in the following photo. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=234552&p=1438618&hilit=electromagnet+tlfong01#p1437850.

Comment: @RodionDegtyar The toroid core you have, type 43, is nice for discontinuous switchers. But it is not so nice for electromagnets. And the shape is a closed loop, so there is no place where you can get direct access to lots of Teslas (webers per square meter) even if you could make them.

Comment: To get a measurable magnetic field with this inductor, grind a gap in it with a cutting wheel on a Dremel, to make a C shape with the smallest gap you can. (May take several cutting wheels!). Then you may be able to detect a magnetic field concentrated in the gap. The reluctance and thus the inductance will reduce, it'll be dominated by the width of the gap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magnetism you see from that coil will be very low.  The main reason is that the wire is wound on to a ring.  That means that the magnetic field has no need to leave the ring. Electromagnets are normally rods, or U-shaped.

The other reason is that you don't have many turns of wire.  Electromagnets have a large number of turns.  The insulation on the wire isn't a problem.

Comment: for use as magnet, doesn't matter how many turns of wire he adds . . .

Comment: @Pete W Yes, but if He uses a I, U core, or gap the existing one - inductance will drop, and to get the same as before more turns will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

re: "doesn't work as a magnet"

Magnetic field outside a toroid is (in principle) zero.